# Generate a normal distribution of dates within a range

Tags: python, date, numpy, gaussian, normal-distribution

I have a date range - say between `1925-01-01` and `1992-01-01`. I'd like to generate a list of `x` dates between that range, and have those `x` dates generated follow a 'normal' (bell curve - see image) distribution.

There are many many answers on stackoverflow about doing this with integers (using `numpy`, `scipy`, etc), but I can't find a solid example with dates

[image]

Comment: Convert your dates to ticks or seconds or some other 1-d unit (which is a very common operation for dates; it's even the natural form internally). Then the location of the normal-dist is for example the middle-element (in your new 1d-form) and you just need to tune the variance/std. Later, you transform the samples back.

Answer (score 5):

As per @sascha's comment, a conversion from the dates to a time value does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import numpy

_DATE_RANGE = ('1925-01-01', '1992-01-01')
_DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
_EMPIRICAL_SCALE_RATIO = 0.15
_DISTRIBUTION_SIZE = 1000

def main():
    time_range = tuple(time.mktime(time.strptime(d, _DATE_FORMAT))
                       for d in _DATE_RANGE)
    distribution = numpy.random.normal(
        loc=(time_range[0] + time_range[1]) * 0.5,
        scale=(time_range[1] - time_range[0]) * _EMPIRICAL_SCALE_RATIO,
        size=_DISTRIBUTION_SIZE
    )
    date_range = tuple(time.strftime(_DATE_FORMAT, time.localtime(t))
                       for t in numpy.sort(distribution))
    print(date_range)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that instead of the `_EMPIRICAL_SCALE_RATIO`, you could (should?) use `scipy.stats.truncnorm` to generate a [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using `datetime` module that also allows to generate hours, minutes, seconds & is using Numpy/Pandas friendly date format.

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy

def main(start, end, date_format,  distribution_size, scale_ratio):
    # Converting to timestamp
    start = datetime.strptime(start, date_format).timestamp()
    end = datetime.strptime(end, date_format).timestamp()
    
    # Generate Normal Distribution
    mu = datetime.strptime('1958-01-01T00:00:00', date_format).timestamp()
    sigma = (end - start) * scale_ratio
    total_distribution = np.random.normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma,  size=distribution_size)
    
    # Sort and Convert back to datetime
    sorted_distribution = numpy.sort(total_distribution)
    date_range = tuple(datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in sorted_distribution)
    print(date_range)



start = '1925-01-01T00:00:00'
end = '1992-01-01T00:00:00'
date_format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

main(start=start, end=end, date_format=date_format, distribution_size=1000, scale_ratio=0.05)
```

Results:

[image]

You can also blend multiple distributions like this:

```
dist_1 = np.random.normal(loc=mu_1, scale=sigma_1,  size=size_1)
dist_2 = np.random.normal(loc=mu_2, scale=sigma_2,  size=size_2)
all_distributions = np.concatenate([dist_1, dist_2])
```